arXiv - is it possible to upload there an abstract and only within a week the text itself?
I want to submit a paper to a journal on which I've worked with a colleague. The paper is almost finished but refers to another unpublished paper I've been working on. To avoid falling behind schedule with my colleague, I am considering uploading my in-progress paper's abstract to arXiv for now, and once I finish working on the paper, I will upload it again to arXiv. Is it possible to upload merely a detailed abstract of a paper and then upload the full-blown complete paper to the arXiv? Please advise.

Papers on arxiv can be updated. Why not publish what you have right now?

@MisterMiyagi thank you. I am still working on part of the section related to 'results' and producing relevant graphs. So I thought to consider uploading the abstract and once I finish my work on it (I think it will take a week or so) to upload a complete paper. I thought it would not be good to just upload parts of a paper, even if they hold the core of it...Do you think it is no good to upload a mere abstract and upload it to a full paper once I complete the writing of it?

@Soni It's a bit unclear why you would want to do this. What's the benefit of uploading right now when you can upload the complete thing in one week? Is there some deadline you need to hit? Are you afraid of getting scooped?

@DCTLib, thank you. Need to meet the deadline for the submission of the paper I co-authored with a colleague, and since that paper refers to the sole-authored paper that I have not yet finished, I somehow need a way to still provide a link to it.  This is the situation for which I am looking for advice...Maybe the best will be to try to submit with the colleague without any hyperlink to arXiv and just write in the reference near the paper "unpublished manuscript", and later once I finish what I need to send the journal a link to my full-blown paper in arXiv (?)

Related question: How to address dependencies when publishing a chain of papers

The Arxiv says it does not accept abstract-only papers.
https://info.arxiv.org/help/policies/content-types.html
This page goes on to say that articles should be "complete final drafts" which is a bit of an oxymoron as drafts are not final.  This is not rigorously enforced, but I would expect an abstract-only paper to be rejected.
Early versions of the other paper can list this as "in preparation" which works best if you don't later change the title.
